# Ajax form submition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm attempting to create a "Save Changes" button for a form that would send data via ajax to the update method in the controller.  The aim is to allow form users to save their work without the form reloading or redirecting.  However I'm running into a bit of a problem; I'm getting the following error

> undefined method `update_incorporation_path'

To be clear, `incorporation` is the controller that we're working with.  Below is the code I added to accomplish this.

**To my view, I added:**

```
<%= button_to "", update_incorporation_path(@incorporation), :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

**To my routes, I added:**

```
resources :incorporations do
  member do
    post 'update'
  end
end
```

**The update method looks like this:**

```
  def update
    if @incorporation.update(incorporation_params)
      if admin_signed_in?
    @incorporations = Incorporation.all.order("created_at DESC")
      else
    @incorporations = current_user.incorporations("created_at DESC")
      end
      render action: "index"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

**The complete view is below:**
**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<br/>
<%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

**_form.html.erb** (the buttons are at the bottom)

```
<div id="wrapper" class="active main-content">
  <%= simple_form_for @incorporation do |f| %>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
      <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu<span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <% @sections=[["basic_info", "Basic Info"],["address", "Address"],["equity", "Equity"],["officers","Officers"],["directors", "Directors"],["contractor","Contractors"],["ip","IP"],["shareholders", "Shareholders"]] %>
      <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
    <% @sections.each do |section| %>
      <li><a href="#<%= section[0] %>" class="anchor_link"><span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span><%= section[1] %></a></li>
    <% end %>
      </ul>
      <div id="save">Save</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="basic_info" class="form_section">

    <div class="form-left"><h2>Basic Info</h2></div>
    <div class="form-right">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company| %>
        <div class="padded-fields">
          <%= render 'basic_fields', company:company %>
        </div>
      <% end =%>
      <div class="padded-fields">
        <div class="form_subsection">
          <%= f.input :trademark_search, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Would you like us to do a trademark search and provide advice regarding any issues we identify in relation to the name you have selected?', input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company| %>

    <div id="address" class="form_section">
      <%= render 'address_fields' , company:company %>
    </div>

    <div id="equity" class="form_section">
      <%= render 'equity_fields' , company:company %>
    </div>

    <div id="officers" class="form_section">
      <div class="form-left"><h2>Officers</h2><br/><p>Please list the officers of the company.</p></div>
      <div class="form-right">
        <div>
          <%= company.simple_fields_for :officers do |officer|%>
            <%= render 'officer_fields', f: officer %>
          <% end =%>
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Officer', company, :officers, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="directors" class="form_section">
      <div class="form-left"><h2>Directors</h2><br/><p>Please list the initial directors of the company.  We recommend an odd number to avoid a deadlocked board.</p></div>
      <div class="form-right">
        <div>
          <%= company.simple_fields_for :people do |person|%>
            <%= render 'person_fields', f: person %>
          <% end =%>
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Director', company, :people, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contractor" class="form_section">
      <div class="form-left"><h2>Employees Contractors</h2></br><p>Please list all employees, independent contractors and any other individual or entity who will be providing services to the company at the time of incorporation.  Each of these persons should have written agreements with the company.  Please check the box next to each name for whom you would like us to prepare agreements</p></div>
      <div class="form-right">
        <div>
          <%= company.simple_fields_for :contractor_people do |contractor| %>
        <%= render 'contractor_person_fields', f:contractor %>
          <% end =%>
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Person', company, :contractor_people, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form_subsection">
          <div>
        <%= company.simple_fields_for :contractor_orgs do |contractor| %>
          <%= render 'contractor_org_fields', f:contractor %>
        <% end =%>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Company', company, :contractor_orgs, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ip" class="form_section">
      <div class="form-left">
        <h2>Intellectual Property</h2><br/><p>Please list existing intellectual property (including business plans, software, artwork, inventions, trade secrets and the like) that has been created for use in the company and the name of the person or people who created it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-right">
        <div>
          <%= company.simple_fields_for :ips do |ip| %>
        <%= render 'ip_fields', f: ip %>
          <% end =%>
          <div class="add-field"><%= link_to_add_association 'Add IP', company, :ips, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="shareholders" class="form_section">
      <div class="form-left"><h2>Shareholders</h2><br/><p>Please list all individuals to hold equity in this company.</p></div>
      <div class="form-right">
        <div>
          <%= company.simple_fields_for :shareholders do |shareholder|%>
            <%= render 'shareholder_fields', f: shareholder %>
          <% end =%>
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Shareholder', company, :shareholders, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <% end =%>
    </div>
    <%= f.button :submit, id:"incorporation_submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), method: :post, remote: true %>
  <% end =%>
</div>
```

I figure I must be forgetting something.  Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes for `update` method was by default added when you wrote `resources :incorporations`, so change your routes to

```
resources :incorporations
```

And your path should be `incorporation_path`, also method in `button_to` is by default `post`, you don't need to write it,

change your `button_to` to

```
<%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), :remote => true %>
```

But, if you are submitting a form, it should have a submit button instead of `button_to`, your form should look like this

```
<%= form_for @incorporation, remote: true do |f| %>
  # form content
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi RSB, thanks for the response! I changed the button and routes as you recommended and it resolved the error message. However, I'm having the problem that it's submitting the form and redirecting. My goal in creating this button is that it would simply save the data on the form and stay on the same view without redirecting or reloading.  I got rid of the `render action: "index"` in the controller and got a `Template is missing` error.  I tried adding a `  render :nothing => true` but that just gave me a blank page when I clicked the button.  Any ideas how I might rectify this?  Thanks again.

Comment: I would be helpful for me if you could post the form code

Comment: I added the view and partial above

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
<%= button_to "", update_incorporation_path(@incorporation), 
   :remote => true, :method => :post %>
```

Try :

```
<%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), 
   method: :post, remote: true %>
```

In your route:

```
resources :incorporations
```

The resources ships with default actions index,new, create,edit, update, destroy. You don't need to declare it manually.

You can verify the routes from your console.

```
 rake routes | grep 'incorporations'
```

You will get output like : 
[image]
From here you can construct your path for the update action. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks for the answer!  I changed the button and routes as you recommended and it resolved the error message.   However, I'm having the problem that it's submitting the form and redirecting.  My goal in creating this button is that it would simply save the data on the form and stay on the same view without redirecting or reloading.  Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?  Many thanks!

Comment: Do this in your controller remove all the redirect_to statements. as the form is submitted with remote: true option, hence this will perform an ajax submit.

Comment: @neanderslob, as I see your update action you have the render statements. Look after the update is done, you don't want to change anything in the view, then simply remove all the render & redirect lines. 

Instantly if want you notify user with any error/success message, then you can, have an update.js.erb in your view folder. This js file will hold your quick notifications being in the same page. :)

Comment: @neanderslob , follow this link. this shows how you can handle any further interactions after your record is saved. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199634/how-do-i-update-my-view-template-once-my-form-is-submitted-via-ajax-in-rails-4/28199866#answer-28199866

Comment: I had thought that might be the issue but when I got rid of the `render action: "index"` and got a `Template is missing` error.  I tried adding a `  render :nothing => true` but that just gave me a blank page when I clicked the button.

Comment: Then in that case your form is not being submitted by the remote: true / ajax option. Just verify your form & the update button holds the remote: true options..

Comment: It looks alright to me.  Just in case, I've copied and pasted the `button_to` line directly: `<%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), method: :post, remote: true %>`

Comment: <%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), 
   method: :post, remote: true %> with this make sure your form holds the similar remote: true option.  <%= form_for(@incorporation, remote: true ) do |f| %>